# How to select from a database using getter and setter methods in PHP

Tags: php, sql, get, set

I need to select/insert data from/to database using getter and setter methods. What I'm trying to achieve for now is to select everything from the db and echo it out in html, to see if I'm receiving anything at all.

This the code so far:

```php
class Products extends DbConnect {

    protected $id;
    protected $sku;
    protected $name;
    protected $price;
    protected $type;
    protected $attributes;

    public function select() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $result = $this->connect()->query($query);

        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->id = $row['Id'];
        $this->sku = $row['SKU'];
        $this->name = $row['Name'];
        $this->price = $row['Price'];
        $this->type = $row['Type'];
        $this->attributes = $row['Attributes'];
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSKU() {
        return $this->sku;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function getAttributes() {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

}
```

I'm not sure what I have to do next. I tried to see if I get any data like this:

```php
public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

$product = new Products();
echo $product->name;
```

It tells me I'm not passing any arguments. Do I have to do something else with the selected data before I print it out? I'm completely new to this approach and I'm not really sure what to do.

Comment: `new Products('Fred Bloggs'); echo $product->getName();`

Comment: Many issues: If you do `SELECT * FROM products` you will get Many results, but you only fetch ONE of those results??

Comment: Also you have to call the `select()` method before you will have any data in all the fields serviced by the getters

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor needs to be in the class

```
class Products extends DbConnect {

    protected $id;
    protected $sku;
    protected $name;
    protected $price;
    protected $type;
    protected $attributes;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function select() {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM products";
        $result = $this->connect()->query($query);

        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->id = $row['Id'];
        $this->sku = $row['SKU'];
        $this->name = $row['Name'];
        $this->price = $row['Price'];
        $this->type = $row['Type'];
        $this->attributes = $row['Attributes'];
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSKU() {
        return $this->sku;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getType() {
        return $this->type;
    }

    public function getAttributes() {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

}
```

Then you pass the parameters when you define the new class

```
$product = new Products("Product Name");
echo $product->name;
```

One thing I would suggest would be to change the constructor to accept an array that way you can pass any number of parameters across and order doesn't matter.

```
public function __construct(array $config = []) {
  $this->name = $config["name"];
  $this->id = $config["id"];
}
```

And then you can send any number of arguments through like this

```
$options = [
  "name" => "ProductName",
  "id" => "ProductID"
];

$product = new Products($options);
echo "Name: ".$product->name;
echo "ID: ".$product->id;
```

Comment: Properties are protected!! So `echo $product->name;` should be `echo $product->getName();`

Comment: This isn't really what I was looking for. It just prints out "Product Name". What I need to do is to get all rows from sql database and echo them out in html, using a foreach loop, most likely. And I need to pass the values as properties through the getter method.